# How to grant permanent permission on Uri images (androidx)

Tags: android, permissions, uri, androidx, android-contentresolver

In my application a user can open the gallery and select their images by using androidX method:

```
registeredIntent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents(), this);
```

And the callback for the result is sent in this method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> result) {
    if(result != null && result.size() > 0) {
        sliderImageAdapter.addItems(result);
        binding.includeResultTask.imageSlider.setSliderAdapter(sliderImageAdapter, true);
    }
}
```

So far this works pretty well, the images are shown in my gallery component by adding the Uris in my adapter, the problem is that I save those in my database and when I restart the application the permissions are revoked and my application crash.
I tried by adding this in my callback for each item:

```
requireActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

But I get this error:

```
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{41a7dce 26094:it.ilogreco.levelup/u0a482} (pid=26094, uid=10482) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I have even tried to use this for each item:

```
context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), uri, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

but I get this error:

```
UID 10482 does not have permission to content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A108953 [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I load the Uris one time and save them to the database with the registerForActivityResult, I can't open the media gallery again with the API because it doesn't make sense, any idea how to get those permissions? I would like to avoid copying the content in the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch from `ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents` to `ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments`. Then, your `takePersistableUriPermission()` calls should work. You can only get persistable `Uri` permissions on documents obtained via the Storage Access Framework, which is what `OpenMultipleDocuments` uses.

Comment: Oh god you have no idea how much time I wasted on this problem and I was 2 words away from the solution, thank you very much :D